# Indexing a 2D numpy array inside a function using a function parameter

Tags: python, function, numpy, slice

Say I have a 2D image in python stored in a numpy array and called npimage (1024 times 1024 pixels).
I would like to define a function ShowImage, that take as a paramater a slice of the numpy array:

```
def ShowImage(npimage,SliceNumpy):
    imshow(npimage(SliceNumpy))
```

such that it can plot a given part of the image, lets say:

```
ShowImage(npimage,[200:800,300:500])
```

would plot the image for lines between 200 and 800 and columns between 300 and 500, i.e.

```
imshow(npimage[200:800,300:500])
```

Is it possible to do that in python? For the moment passing something like [200:800,300:500] as a parameter to a function result in error.

Thanks for any help or link.
Greg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible because `[...]` are a syntax error when not directly used as `slice`, but you could do:

- Give only the relevant sliced image - not with a seperate argument `ShowImage(npimage[200:800,300:500])` (no comma)
- or give a `tuple` of `slices` as argument: `ShowImage(npimage,(slice(200,800),slice(300:500)))`. Those can be used for slicing inside the function because they are just another way of defining this slice:

  ```
  npimage[(slice(200,800),slice(300, 500))] == npimage[200:800,300:500]
  ```

---

A possible solution for the second option could be:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def ShowImage(npimage, SliceNumpy):
    plt.imshow(npimage[SliceNumpy])
    plt.show()

ShowImage(npimage, (slice(200,800),slice(300, 500)))
# plots the relevant slice of the array.
```

Comment: hei, thanks that works perfectly. I like the second solution better though.